# clojure lazy sequences and letfn

Tags: recursion, clojure

I'm trying some lazy streams in Clojure.
If I do:

```
(defn ints-from [n]
   (cons n (lazy-seq (ints-from (inc n)))))
```

and

```
(def nats (ints-from 0))
```

it's fine, I can do something like:

```
(take 5 nats)
```

Now I'm trying to encapsulate the 2 functions in 1:

```
(defn natz[]
( letfn   [(aux [n]((cons n (lazy-seq (aux (inc n)))))) ] (aux 0) ))
```

This seems to compile, but does not do what I expect.

```
(take 4 natz)
```

gives:

```
(user=> IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: user$natz    
clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:494)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One parenthesis less inside letfn definition and one parenthesis more to invoke natz function

```
(defn natz[]
  (letfn [(aux [n] (cons n (lazy-seq (aux (inc n)))))]
    (aux 0)))
```

Example usage:

```
(take 4 (natz))
=> (0 1 2 3)
```